# Stopping an Android app from console

Tags: android, testing, adb

Is it possible to stop an Android app from the console? Something like:

```
adb stop com.my.app.package
```

It would speed up our testing process so much. Right now we uninstall/install the app each time to make sure the manual test cases start with a clean state.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

**Edit:** Long after I wrote this post and it was accepted as the answer, the `am force-stop` command was [implemented](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/351f322) by the Android team, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274218/234938).

**Alternatively:** Rather than just stopping the app, since you mention wanting a "clean slate" for each test run, you can use `adb shell pm clear com.my.app.package`, which will stop the app process *and* clear out all the stored data for that app.

---

If you're on Linux:
`adb shell ps | grep com.myapp | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill`

That will only work for devices/emulators where you have root immediately upon running a shell.  That can probably be refined slightly to call `su` beforehand.

Otherwise, you can do (manually, or I suppose scripted):
`pc $ adb -d shell`
`android $ su`
`android # ps`
`android # kill <process id from ps output>`

Comment: Couldn't get it to work (permission denied both for kill and su), but +1 for showing me I can do lots more than I thought with adb.

Comment: Ah, sounds like you don't have a rooted device. It definitely works on the emulator at least! :)

Comment: Maybe you have to remount the partition read-write and run adb as root: adb remount; adb root # that's just a stupid guess thought

Comment: `adb shell ps | grep com.myapp | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell su -0 kill` works for me

Comment: Clear command is perfect, it does exactly what op wants, equivalent to swiping up in task manager screen.

Answer (score 778):

The clean way of stopping the app is:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.my.app.id
```

This way you don't have to figure out the process ID.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this problem. The question doesn't include a rooted device.

Comment: @Dimitris I wrote my answer above before the `force-stop` command existed. I updated my answer to point to this one.

Comment: Also I updated my answer with a good way of really providing a "clean slate" for running tests.

Comment: Important point that after this your BroadcastReceiver will not work (till next app open) https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Comment: Tested on `Android 9.0 API Level 28`, the app still is displayed in the **Recent Apps** even though the `PID` is found regarding the app. Do you know how to stop the app **completely** which means even from the background apps?

Answer (score 46):

First, put the app into the background (press the device's home button)

Then....in a terminal....

```
adb shell am kill com.your.package
```

Comment: ***NOTE*** I don't believe this works anymore in APIs levels > 22.

Comment: it does on my Nexus 5 with Marshmallow

Comment: This works.  Make sure you put the app into the background first though.

Answer (score 19):

you can use the following from the device console: `pm disable com.my.app.package` which will kill it. Then use `pm enable com.my.app.package` so that you can launch it again.

Comment: On a non-rooted phone this seems to do nothing.

Comment: I've checke it on a non-rooted phone. At first there are some permission denied messages and then it killed my DalvicVM app/service. Just give it a sec.

Comment: on a rooted device this works, and it has the added benefit of being able to keep the app/service down.  This may be desirable for testing purposes.

Comment: Note: You need to `adb shell`, then run `su` first.

Comment: Warning, this will make the launcher icon shortcuts for that package disappear, even after re-enabling.

Comment: This can be used on Android 2.3 or below to kill the app from the task. Since there is no way to kill an app.

Comment: Yes, this only works with root. Instead of `am force-stop ...` this is the only way that prevents the app to automatically restart it (e. g. in a kiosk mode)

Answer (score 10):

If you have access to the application package, then you can install with the -r option and it will kill the process if it is currently running as a side effect. Like this:

`adb -d install -r MyApp.apk ; adb -d shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.MyCompany.MyApp/.MyActivity`

The -r option preserves the data currently associated with the app. However, if you want a clean slate like you mention you might not want to use that option.

Answer (score 8):

If you target a non-rooted device and/or have services in you APK that you don't want to stop as well, the other solutions won't work.

To solve this problem, I've resorted to a broadcast message receiver I've added to my activity in order to stop it.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String STOP_COMMAND = "com.example.TestActivity.STOP";

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TestActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //other stuff...

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(STOP_COMMAND));
    }
}
```

That way, you can issue this adb command to stop your activity:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.TestActivity.STOP
```

Answer (score 7):

The "stop" command is implemented as `force-stop`; stops background app from running. If it's in foreground, it'll stop also: eg.

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.providers.telephony
```

Clearing of packages also deletes their data eg.

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.telephony
```

will delete all your sms

Be careful which one you choose.

Answer (score 4):

`adb shell killall -9 com.your.package.name`

according to MAC "mandatory access control"
you  probably have the permission to kill process
which is not started by root

have fun!

Comment: I am getting "Operation not permitted" in the response to running this command

Answer (score 2):

I tried all answers here on Linux nothing worked for debugging on unrooted device API Level 23,
so i found an Alternative for debugging
From Developer Options -> Apps section -> check Do Not keep activities
that way when ever you put the app in background it gets killed

P.S remember to uncheck it after you finished debugging

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking for is killing a package

```
pkill package_name
```

should work

Comment: Note: this only works on newer Android versions. pkill is not available on my 4.4 emulator but is available on the Android 6 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to the DDMS perspective and in the devices tab click the process you want to kill under the device you want to kill it on. You then just need to press the stop button and it should kill the process.

I'm not sure how you'd do this from the command line tool but there must be a way. Maybe you do it through the adb shell...

Comment: I've found a [code snippet on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/805605) on how to do this from the command line without running Eclipse and [extended it slightly](https://gist.github.com/3175409).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used

```
adb shell pidof com.payjoy.status | xargs adb shell kill
```

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the permission problem by starting the app from a console with:
adb shell monkey -p your.process.name -v 1
then consequently I have the permission to kill it with:
adb shell am force-stop your.process.nam

Answer (score -2):

```
pkill NAMEofAPP
```

Non rooted marshmallow, termux & terminal emulator.

Comment: It is still alive in termux.