# Unpin application with adb shell commands in android lollipop

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, android-screen-pinning

**Summary**

Is there a way to unpin apps in lollipop using shell commands

with adb iv tried:

```
adb shell input keyevent --longpress 4 187
```

but this never worked

**Why i want to do this**

1) i'm making a root application that replaces the on screen navigation buttons and need a way to unpin other apps

2) when using a virtual device and i pin a app there is no way for me to press back and recents at the same time with my mouse

Comment: in development, just being able to kill the app helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3117310/379767

Answer (score 1):

Try this command to unpin the foreground app:

```
am task lock stop `dumpsys activity | grep -A2 "(dumpsys activity recents)"| grep '#'| cut -d ' ' -f 7| cut -c 2-`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell am task lock stop `dumpsys activity | grep -A2 '(dumpsys
activity recents)'| grep '#'| cut -d ' ' " \
                "-f 7| cut -c 2-
```

This works with Android 9+ devices

Answer (score -1):

This works with android 4.4.2

```
adb shell su -c 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.launcher/databases/launcher.db "DELETE from favorites"'
```