# why is com.android.phone still showing in processes?

Tags: android, adb

I killed com.android.phone using

```
adb shell kill pid
```

But when i run

```
adb shell ps
```

i can still find this process. Which application started it again.Are there certain packages which are always restarted by android by itself?

Comment: You cant  kill system services

Comment: how to know that com.android.phone is system service. What are the other system services?

Comment: Have a read http://forums.androidcentral.com/optimus-v-rooting-roms-hacks/156703-guide-apk-s-their-purpose-safe-not-remove-big.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117095/stopping-an-android-app-from-console

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some of the system apps will always suppose to be running for the consistency of android OS.

com.android.phone is one of them.

Comment: my question is what are the other system apps. Can i list down all the system app used by my android by some adb command or any other method.

Comment: You need root access to access the system apps.