# Removing App from background using Appium

Tags: appium

is there any way to remove app from background using Appium in Windows.

What i want is
- Start server with -No reset
-Run the program
-Program ends
-driver quits using driver.quit() method

Now when i start my test execution again , the app on which i was earlier working is there in the memory.So i have to press "Home" key and remove it from memory and then start working on it. (e.g. if i am working on messaging app of device , after test execution i press "Home" hardkey and manually remove the app as follows)[image]
Please help me how to do this

Comment: you can try to launch `adb shell am force-stop com.my.app.package` from the command line: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117095/stopping-an-android-app-from-console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117095/stopping-an-android-app-from-console)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `driver.closeApp()` before `driver.quit()`. 
Please see [this link](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#) with the different appium methods provide app control.