# Is it possible to programmatically ask Android to SaveInstanceState?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and making my first real app and it uses the `socket.io` Java Client for communicating with my `Node.JS` server instance. I have recently discovered while testing that the OS can kill background apps whenever it feels necessary calling `onSaveInstanceState()` on the active `Activity` then when you switch back to the app it recreates the previous state using the `Bundle` passed as an argument in the `onCreate()` method.

So now that I know that, I need to implement a solution that would keep the app working as it should so I expect I will have to test a few solutions before I get the right one. And since it would be so time-consuming to just lock my screen and watch the server logs waiting for the

`User disconnected`

(which can take a lot of time for each try), I wondered if anyone here ever was in the same situation and figured a way to make the OS kill the app as soon as I lock the screen or hit the Volume Down button or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried "Developer Options / Do not Keep Activities" at device settings? With this option activities are being destroyed immediately as soon as the user leaves them.

Comment: I've just tried this : it seems like `onSaveInstanceState()` is called but the `socket.io` connexion keeps active whereas when the app gets killed after long screen lock, the `socket.io` connexion stops

Comment: Also just tried removing this option, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called anyway as soon as i hit the Home button

Comment: With this option your activity's onDestroy method will be invoked when you leave your activity. Maybe you can close connection under onDestroy method programmatically?

Comment: If I close the connection under `onDestroy()` of every Activity that uses `socket.io`, I will lose all the benefits of having a persistent connection.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Are you looking for an answer to kill your app any time? If so check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117095/stopping-an-android-app-from-console

Comment: What I am currently looking for to be precise is a way to replicate the natural behaviour of Android (ie. killing background apps) the way it usually do. I think the closest I got is with your first comment but for some reason it seems like the app is not really killed even though the activity is. I know that because the `socket.io` connexion isn't terminated with this method.