# [Android]How to pass a process number to cmd line "adb shell kill "

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, awk

I would like to find a specific target's pid and kill this process.

Then, i made a shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

func(){

while true; do 

adb shell ps | grep my-target-process | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill 

sleep 1

done
}
```

But, i always get  errors like below :

```
usage:  kill [-s signame | -signum | -signame] { job | pid | pgrp } ...
    kill -l [exit_status ...]
```

Is there anything wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you try xargs -I{} adb shell kill {}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117095/stopping-an-android-app-from-console

Comment: It works,  thank you.
Would you please specify why?  thanks

Comment: @Sweet: Are you referring to my suggestion? and which Android version are you using? Is it  `6.0` and higher?

Comment: @lnian  yes, I follow your suggestion.  My Android version is  Android 7.0

Comment: @Vinodh : thank you!

Comment: @Inian sure,  thank U so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add an explanation the logic I suggested in the comments section. The reason why

```
| xargs -I{} adb shell kill "{}"
```

works is, with the `-I{}` flag in `xargs`, the `{}` becomes a placeholder for the output returned from the previous command, i.e. the process-id is now present in `{}` and can be passed as an argument/input to your `kill` command.

(also) As an alternative, if your `Android` version supports `pidof` command, which returns the process-id `pid` directly, you can do

```
adb shell pidof -s "my-target-process" | xargs -I{} kill "{}"
```

Comment: @lnian  sorry for late, i was in a global trip previously,  thanks very much for your clarification