# How to force stop an app with Android Studio to test background lifecycle mechanism?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-background

**So I would like to test what happens with my application when the user puts it to the background** and after a while the OS would free up memory thus kill the app, and I would like to re-open it again to see whether my states are restored etc.

I remember (maybe badly) **there was a red stop button on the left side of logcat which would kill the app in if you put it to the background.** Right? I think it was removed in the recent update of Android Studio maybe?

---

I'm talking about this area (place of the stop button (was))

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What about killing using adb: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117095/stopping-an-android-app-from-console?

Comment: A nitpick: you want to avoid anything that actually _force stops_ the app, as force stop does a lot more than what happens when the OS kills the process (for example, force stop removes jobs, alarms, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play/Stop buttons are now placed in Run tab. Since there is the possibility to have multiple logcats, you need to manage the app status in the Run tab.

Regards.